# elapsed time lower than higher score game center

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, game-center, elapsedtime

I am wondering how to make sure that how lower the elapsed time is, how higher the score in Apple's game center is. When I have a time '12 secs' and a time '15 secs' later, the '15 secs' will be recognized as the highest score now. How can I solve this?

This is my code I use for submitting:

```
        self.gameCenterManager = [[GameCenterFiles alloc] init];
        [self.gameCenterManager setDelegate:self];
        int my_time = 12;
        NSLog(@"%i", my_time);

        [self.gameCenterManager reportScore:my_time forCategory: self.currentLeaderBoard];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a setting you make in iTunesConnect, not in your code, as that is where the characteristics of the leaderboard are configured.

Comment: I only can choose if the lowest or the highest score is displayed first, best score or recent score displayed. Does that mean that you can set there that the lowest score is the best score?

Comment: Yes, that is what the order represents.